# Can't find extarnal classes in Mono mcs C#

Tags: c#, mono

I’m running Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 8.1. I am struggling with a console application project.

The solution works fine in Visual Studio 2015, but when I try to compile it with mcs-compiler I get two errors (Kattis codetest use mcs-kompiler). Two external classes can not be found.

***I'm getting the following error:***

> Program.cs(28,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Graph'
>   could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>   Program.cs(58,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name`Solver'
>   could not b e found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>   Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

The code is large so a I have pasted in just parts of it:
The Program class, where main is and the calls to ”Graph” and ”Solver” are made from:

```
    Call in  Program.cs:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     // first call: 
    var edges = CliquesToEdges(cliques);
                sudokuColour.Graph graph = new Graph(81, edges); 

                string line = "";
                string storeLine = "";
                string puzzle = "";
.
.
.
    // second call:
                for (int i = 0; i < store.Count(); i++)
                {
                    puzzle = store.ElementAt(i);

                    sudokuColour.Solver solver = new Solver(graph, 9);

                    int node = -1;
                    foreach (char c in puzzle)
                    {
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Beginning of "Graph" class:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using sudokuColour;

   namespace sudokuColour
   {
        public class Graph
        {
    .
    .
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Beginning of "Solver" class:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using sudokuColour;

    namespace sudokuColour
    {  
        public class Solver
        {
            private enum Result { Solved, Unsolved, Busted }
            private readonly Graph graph;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can the error be?

Comment: Please take the time to [edit] your question and format the code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudokuColour.Solver solver = new Solver(graph, 9);
```

The fact that you had to namespace-qualify it on the left probably means you should namespace-qualify it on the right too:

```
sudokuColour.Solver solver = new sudokuColour.Solver(graph, 9);
```

Alternatively, add a using directive at the top of the code file:

```
using sudokuColour;
```

or:

```
using Solver = sudokuColour.Solver;
```

---

likewise for:

```
sudokuColour.Graph graph = new Graph(81, edges);
```

---

If that still doesn't work: you're probably missing a project reference (or package reference, or assembly reference - but a project reference seems the most appropriate) between the two projects.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
I’ve tried to add namespace according the advice above, but it does not help.
I get the same error
But how do I do do add a project-reference ( or maybe a assembly reference)?

Comment: @MatsNyström are you using Visual Studio? Right click on the project and add reference...

Comment: When I open the reference manager window there are two options:""Solutions" and "Assemblies". Under "Solutions" there are nothing at all. What files should I add here?

Comment: @MatsNyström "projects"; if this is a translation thing, then it sounds closest to "projects"

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but I have no idea what to add under "Solutions. Do have any link to further information?

Comment: @MatsNyström it should already list the other projects in the solution; just put a check mark against the one(s) you want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/im33g.png